# Job searching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search

My issue seems simple enough to me, but I can't break it down the the bare essentials to be able to program it into my game.

First of all different professions requires different skills, these skills are contained inside the class `Person`. I have a `world map` where I can ask for all empty buildings, thereby finding all available jobs.

With this information I want to calculate from some weights that the player can modify on each profession to how important it is to be fill a certain position.

so my current approach would be something like this pseudo code:

```
    Job findJob(wm : WorldMap) {
      Queue priority <- empty;
      for each building {
        queue.add(skill * need);
      }
      return prority.max();
    }
```

Does that sound inefficient stupid or do you see any special cases that you think I should be aware of?

Comment: How does the `empty building` glue together with `job` and `skill`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `empty building` but the idea is that every building can give me a job with a certain skill need. Also the types are not well defined in this pseudo code nor correct

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to find the maximum building you don't need any queue. Just keep the current maximum in a variable and replace it if you find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Probably this would be another pseudo code which may help:

  Job findJob(wm : WorldMap) {
  for each portals from job portal1 to http://9kriwala.com
  Queue priority <- empty;
  for each building {
    queue.add(skill * need);
  }
  return prority.max();
  }
```